# excel access denied with win32 python pywin32

Tags: python, excel, winapi, pywin32, win32com

My code is

```
#Opens template for creating final report
excel = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
template = os.path.abspath((folderpath+'\Poop.xlsx'))
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(template)
freshws= wb.Sheets("Fresh") #Sheet names must match perfectly
secws= wb.Sheets("sec")

cur.execute("Select * from FIRALL")
freshdata=list(cur.fetchall())
#writes to the first sheet
datarowlen=0
for i,a in enumerate(freshdata):
    datarowlen = len(a)
    for j,b in enumerate(a):
        freshws.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = a[j]

cur.execute("Select * from SECVE")
secdata=list(cur.fetchall())
#writes to the second sheet
datarowlen=0
for i,a in enumerate(secdata):
    datarowlen = len(a)
    for j,b in enumerate(a):
        secws.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = a[j]
#saves the report
wb.SaveAs()
wb.Close()
```

The error i get when I run my code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 369, in <module>
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(template)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel'
, "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'path to stuff------------------------
Poop Report\\Poop.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n\u2022 The file
name or path does not exist.\n\u2022 The file is being used by another program.\
n\u2022 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently ope
n workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I get a popup dialog saying access is denied. The file isn't readonly and I'm the owner of the workbook its trying to open. I've tried

```
win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

I still get the same error. Is there something I'm missing? I switched to dynamic thinking late-binding would solve this error.

another error I had was Pywins -2147418111 error when I was trying to fix this code.

Comment: Where does your `folderpath` variable come from? Because it looks like you're passing Excel the path `'path to stuff------------------------
Poop Report\\Poop.xlsx'`, which is obviously not a valid path, adn that's exactly why you're getting that error.

Comment: I just put that in there to conceal the pathway, the pathways not the issue as I've used openpyxt without problems, however it can't handle pivot tables or update them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up fixing it for some reason this works, if someone could comment why I would appreciate that.

Main thing I changed to open the workbook was the slashes from / to \ in the pathways.

Then I couldn't select the sheet name until I made excel visible.

```
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open((excelreport+"\Poop.xlsx"))
```

Oddly enough that got rid of the pywins error

Also changed how sheets are filled its now

```
cur.execute("Select * from FIRALL")
freshdata=list(cur.fetchall())
#writes to the first sheet
freshws.Range(freshws.Cells(2,1),freshws.Cells((len(freshdata)+1),len(freshdata[0]))).Value = freshdata
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else who runs into the same issues I did.

Comment: Even though the excel file contain correct write access, this error could have happened due to slowness.

I guess the issue could be due to our Excel application is slow to respond while using win32 module, Before performing SaveAs, made code sleep for 5 seconds helped me fix this issue.

Answer (score 17):

A colleague and I were diagnosing this exact issue.  I couldn't believe how obscure this was and we found the solution by searching similar issues with .NET equivalent code:

To fix, create a folder called 'Desktop' in 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\' on 64bit architecture or 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\' on 32bit servers.

This genuinely fixed an absolutely identical issue.

Comment: I can't believe this was it. Thank you based SO, thank you Matthew. I don't know whether to laugh or cry now.

Comment: This works, but why? Why TF would Windows have such an random bug? How would these directories come into play? How did you figure this out?

Comment: almost 10 years later and I also stumbled to this issue. This time, however, it occurs when I am triggering excel in AWS EC2 via AWS lambda.

Thank you for solving this issue, Matthew! I told my colleague and we absolutely lost it

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue please follow the below steps.
Open DCOMCNFG in RUN,
expand Component Services > My Computer > DCOM Config and find Microsoft Excel Application > Properties(right click) -> under the Identity tab set it to "The interactive user for background services.

[image]

[image]